# Create custom module, with javascript and load javascript into footer

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have been assigned to create joomla template from HTML template, and this is first time for me. In HTML template I have a custom JS, and as far I can tell, I will need to create one, or maybe two custom modules in order to recreate functionality that exists. Is there some way to write JS for specific module and load it in footer (this module will be active only on one page, so I don't want to load JS on all pages). Is it possible to do this, or the simplest way is to load JS on everypage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the Joomla documentation on creating modules [Creating a simple module](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aCreating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module) and then on your module file mod_mymodule.php add the script call using:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript( JUri::root() . "media/your_js_directory/your_script.js" );
```

Hope it helps.